# Update database in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server

When I check SharePoint database, found the following messing "Database is in compatibility range and upgrade is recommended", how to update the database?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to resolve it:

Run the cmdlet “Upgrade-SPContentDatabase” on the contend database once, which should resolve the problem.

```
Get-SPContentDatabase -Identity <database-name> | Upgrade-SPContentDatabase
```

Run PSConfig command line:

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

Comment: Is there any progress on this thread? Please feel free to let me know.